# urlencode & SQL request does not work... (cUrl and html special chars seems not to work)

Tags: php, sql, curl, urlencode

**First part of the question solved. Please look at EDIT 2**

I have the following problem:
I get a username out of my database with a `htmlspecialchar`, in this case: `exámple`. I parse it via `cUrl` to the Riot-Games API.

```
$url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/exámple?api_key=<my-api-key>'
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

return $output;

curl_close($ch);
```

My result is: `{ "status": { "message": "Not Found", "status_code": 404 } }`
**But** the user exists! I can open the URL in my browser and it works...

I think `cUrl` can't parse the **á** in the string, if i copy the url and open it in browser

> `á` is converted to `%C3%A1`

Is it somehow possible to convert the URL in `PHP` to a sendable request?

Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT**

If i use `ex%C3%A1mple` instead of `exámple` in my user-database it works!

**EDIT 2**

I now use `urlencode` to the username. **However** I'm despairing...

My simple script:

```
echo urlencode($row["username"]) . " " . urlencode('exámple');
```

The `$row["username"]` outputs me guaranteed `'exámple'`. It's an SQL request.

The output i get:

> ex%E1mple ex%C3%A1mple

**Solved:**

`urlencode(utf8_encode($row["username"]))`

Comment: urlencode the string before passing it to curl. so it should be urlencode(Your database value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `urlencode` function to encode name. See below code:

```
$name='exámple';
$encoded_name = urlencode('exámple'); //output: ex%C3%A1mple

$url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/'.$encoded_name.'?api_key=<my-api-key>';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
```

Comment: Why does my encoded user string look like: `ex%E1mple` ?

Comment: what does `$row["username"]` have?

Comment: i am surprised? can you check var_dump of both?

Comment: Ok, please wait a few mins

Comment: As expected: `string(7) "exámple"` **both**

Comment: I solved my problem with `urlencode(utf8_encode($row["username"]))`. I think it was the wrong charset